# Why there is a constant voice notification on my Mac?

Tags: macos, voice, virus

Every minute there is a woman's voice saying 'helo' (it doesn't sound like 'hello'…) coming from my MacBook (OS X 10.10).

It is freaking me out. I tried closing all my Apps and rebooting my Mac, but it keeps coming out all the same. I tried turning off the Wi-Fi, but it is still there! This voice starts even though I don't log into the desktop after rebooting!

Is it a weird virus on Mac or my Mac has been cursed?

Comment: Since you answered that your Voice Control is OFF, try changing the Voice to see if it is coming from there anyway. You might have downloaded something from the Web. Look in the Activity Monitor to see if you can find a process that does that. Or use alt+cmd+esc and in the new screen see what is running.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have not accidentally turned on voice commands?

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1879370

Try `command+F5`.

Comment: It does not resolve my problem. The Voice Over is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting into [Safe Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262). From the kb entry:

1. Be sure your Mac is shut down.
2. Press the power button.
3. Immediately after you hear the startup sound, press and hold the Shift key. The Shift key should be pressed as soon as possible after startup, but not before the startup sound.
4. Release the Shift key when you see the Apple logo appear on the screen.

After this if the sounds still happens, you might want to consider your options on restoring to a known good backup.

Comment: The sound device is disabled in the Safe Mode. So I still can't find any clue...